# remove space from start and end position of tags in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

input xml:

```
<label>1.1 </label>

<title> Testing</title>

<p> This is subsection </p>
```

output xml:

```
<label>1.1</label>

<title>Testing</title>

<p>This is subsection</p>
```

whatever the tag will be, i want to closeup the value with tags. Either the space at start position or at end position.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a template for text nodes

```
<xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

then any leading or trailing white space in text nodes that are not only white space is removed. For the other nodes you can use the identity transformation template to copy them unchanged:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you also can have mixed contents (i.e. elements containing both element children as well as text node children) and don't want to subject them to the treatment then change the match pattern to `<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]/text()[normalize-space()]">` or perhaps then simply use

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^\s+|\s+$', '')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You might want to help OP make special provisions for mixed content, else `<e>See <b>Spot</b> run.</e>` will become `<e>See<b>Spot</b>run.</e>`.

Comment: @kjhughes, you are right, mixed content might require a different approach, I have added two suggestions that might help in that case.

Comment: That'll probably cover it his needs.  Another, more involved, solution might special-case the first and last text nodes in mixed content to trim any respective leading or trailing spaces selectively.